# Update Column based on Date Offset in Python

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to update a column in a dataset that contains many dates. If the date falls within the last 3 months (of the dataset), then I'd like to update a column that says 'Last 3 Months'

I think I need to use this:

```
today = date.today()
offsetweek = today - pd.offsets.Week(8)
df = df1[Date >= offsetweek]
```

However, the `date.today()` only looks at the current date as opposed to the maximum date in my dataset and do a offset from there.

**Example Output**

[image: Output]

Could someone advise me on how to achieve this?

Comment: `max_date = df["Date"].max()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get maxdate:

```
maxdate = df['Date'].max()
```

Use offset.MonthBegin:

```
offsetby3months = maxdate - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(4)
```

Use np.where:

```
df['Last 3 Months'] = np.where(df['Date'] >= offsetby3months, 'Last 3 Months', '')
```